# Parse.com - User or (Driver and Rider)

Tags: database, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

Quick doubt. I am creating an Uber-clone app for training purposes. Using Parse Dashboard, I am thinking about creating a Rider and a Driver class, but all users should log in as a `PFUser`, shouldn't they?

So, should I:

1) Have only one class of `PFUser`s that already come as the standard?

or

2) Should I create a new Rider or Driver object to each user that signs up (so, if user comes from main app it is a rider and a Rider object is created and associated with the `PFUser` that signed up and similarly for a driver through the Driver app)?

Second approach seems like bad for me because it needs to create a `Rider` or `Driver` object for each `User` being signed up, which does not sound very efficient. On the other hand, having both riders and drivers as a single `User` class which is the standard would have attributes that are used and others that are not (so rider attributes would not be used in driver `User`s). Sounds fine to me, but wouldn't it be bad in terms of query performance since through this option I would have to search for a single rider or driver in, e.g 2M `Users`, instead of 1.5M `Rider`s and 0.5M `Driver`s?

If you can think of a better approach, I would be delighted to hear.

Comment: Create `Driver` and `Rider` `PFUser` subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Roles exist, so you could add each user to a Driver or Rider role. While much of the profile data will be similar between the two roles, there will likely be some differences. Depending on the amount of dissimilar data, you may want to consider separate RiderData / DriverData objects associated with each user anyway, but using the roles can be very helpful in terms of seeing if the user should go to the driver / rider side of the app and when querying for users, or even adding CLP / ACLs that are Role based, so only Drivers can see other fares, and only Riders can see the Drivers nearby.